# Jquery collapsible UI Tabs, collapse tab when icon is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

With collapsible tabs the tab toggles the content open and closed. I still want clicking the tab to open the content but I want the user to click an icon to collapse the tab. How would I implement that?

Here is a link to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8PNN/1/).

```
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    selected: -1,
    collapsible: true
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be best solution. But important thing is to make it workable.

Try this If it helps to solve your scenario

```
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    selected: -1,
    collapsible: true
});
$(".ui-icon-close").click(function(){
    var attrValue = $(this).parent().attr("aria-controls");
    if ($("#" + attrValue).is(':visible'))
    $(this).prev().click();
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8PNN/3/

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the best way either but it works for me.

Comment: Yes, as main thing is to make it workable. I am glad that this solved your problem for now.